# Create a list like object using a bitarray

Tags: python, data-structures, bitarray

I need to track a set of perhaps 10 million numbers in Python.  (All numbers are between 0 and 2^32).  I'll know before hand the max val of an integer, and, between 0 and max, between 20-80% of the values will be in the set.

My current code uses the built in `set`.  This way too slow.  As far as performance is considered, the best way to do this is with a bitarray (such as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/ ).

It's easy for me to use a bitarray to build a class with `add(n)` and `remove(n)` methods.  What I don't know how to do is support `for n in bitarray_set:`.  I think I need to use an iterator or iterable, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Is this possible? How?

Comment: 10 million numbers out of a possible 4 billion may not be efficient for a bitset. You might need something a bit more clever.

Comment: @user2357112 - I added more details why it is efficient

Comment: Okay, that should be plenty efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bitarray`s support an `itersearch` method that iterates over all positions where one bitarray occurs in another. Use that:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self.bits.itersearch(bitarray([True]))
```

Comment: That gives a segfault[1]: from bitarray import *
In [2]: b = bitarray([True, False, True, True, False])
In [3]: b.itersearch(bitarray([True]))
zsh: segmentation fault ipython

Comment: Found the segfault just as you posted and just submitted it https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray/issues/12

Comment: I can't see what the problem is. Looks like a bug in the bitarray module; even if I've misunderstood the interface somehow, this shouldn't be a segfault.

Comment: Maybe use a numpy array if bitarray isn't stable enough. The interface is a bit less convenient, and you'll have to do a bit more work calling `packbits` and `unpackbits` in appropriately-sized chunks, but it should still work.