# Python array for bool values?

Tags: python

I know `array.array` allows to have int/float array. How to have bool array? Memory efficient. so that 1 value is stored as 1 bit. does `array` support it?

Comment: probably not ... and if that concerns you , python may not be the ideal language for this project

Comment: `array.array` isn't `numpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing to store booleans *this* efficiently in native Python, but you can checkout the [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) library which is I think what you are looking for.

Comment: I've seen some stability issues with `bitarray`. There seems to be a segfault affecting the [`itersearch`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981959/create-a-list-like-object-using-a-bitarray) method, at least. I'm not sure whether the module is actively maintained, so there might not be fixes coming.

Comment: I did not have any problem while using it with Python 3 (for what I used it at least). I checked out the [Github issue](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray/issues/12) you are probably talking about but I could not reproduce it. Are you still having the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(int)
436
>>> sys.getsizeof(bool)
436
>>> sys.getsizeof(bool())
12
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
12
>>>
```

basically even if you could you would not get any space saving ...

this may also be of interest

["sys.getsizeof(int)" returns an unreasonably large value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365624/sys-getsizeofint-returns-an-unreasonably-large-value)

Comment: This doesn't help me with "array" sctruct.

Comment: it was more to demonstrate that a bool is more than 1 bit in python

Comment: Ye, i know, so I need "not native" struct.